# SSIS Bulk Insert Sorting in TempDB with SQL Server Destination

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS package created using SQL Server Data Tools deployed to a SQL Server 2012 instance that goes through a process of moving a large amount of data from one database to another on the same server using the SQL Server Destination object.

I am using an OLE DB Source object with a SQL query provided that is sorted in the order of the clustered index of my staging table.  I have the Source object flagged in the advanced editor that the data is sorted and have the column's SortKeyPosition set to 1 as well.  I believe this should avoid hitting TempDB, but I am still seeing a lot of activity on TempDB during execution.  The package is the only thing running on the server currently.

Below is the process the package executes.  If I run the exact same package swapping in an OLE DB Destination, the data goes right into the .mdf file with no activity on TempDB.    The package runs in about 30 minutes using the SQL Server Destination and in about 20 minutes using the OLE DB Destination.  I would just use the OLE DB Destination but it is sporadically throwing network errors like this: "Protocol error in TDS stream".

I have read through a lot of white papers and articles on the issue and they all seem to describe the process I am using and all suggest using the SQL Destination object over the OLE DB object for performance gains. (Ex: http://sql10.blogspot.com/2010/07/ssis-check-list-for-minimally-logged.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(SQL.100).aspx).

Step 1) Truncate staging table

Step 2) Disable all non-clustered indexes on the staging table

Step 3) Remove the primary key constraint from the staging table

Step 4) Copy data to staging table

Step 5) Enable all non-clustered indexes on the staging table

Step 6) Add the primary key back to the staging table

Is there a setting in the SQL Destination object that I am missing or something else that might cause this activity?  Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Yeah, we've made sure the network drivers are updated and turned off the TCP chimney feature. We've also tried adding a different NIC with no luck.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you tried an [ADO.NET Destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895291.aspx) with [Use bulk insert when available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934041.aspx) selected?

Comment: I have not tried an ADO.NET Destination yet. I will try to set that up and test tomorrow and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

Your information is out-of-date - OLE DB Destination is now preferred, both for flexibility and also speed, ref:

http://www.mattmasson.com/index.php/2012/06/should-i-use-the-sql-server-destination/

Your results would seem to confirm that.